# How to create EXE setup file for windows service created in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a `windows service` to detect desktop lock and unlock. I tried to create an EXE setup file (myapp.exe) for my windows service. the service detects lock/unlock event and writes it in a text file.

I was able to do this in `visual studio 2010`, but i don't find any documents as how to create this exe setup file using `visual studio 2012`. I found some videos in youtube which shows creating exe setup file but when i tried i don't find my service installed as a windows service. It is installing like normal application.

Answer (score 3):

Good article explaining how to create a windows service installer with Visual Studio and WiX is available [here](http://www.chrissurfleet.co.uk/post/2011/08/04/Creating-windows-service-installer-with-Visual-Studio-and-WiX.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

With Visual Studio 2012 you will need a third party tool to create setups. I would suggest [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/). There is good information on installing and starting Windows Services using WiX [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/net-and-net/services-rendered) although you will probably need to read some beginners tutorials first.

Comment: thanks. i think it can be done with "install shield" but not sure how to do it for windows service.

Comment: Yes, it probably can be done using InstallShield. I got at least 3 promising links just putting "installshield windows service" into google, one of them from SE.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to load your project in VS2010 and add a setup project there. You will need to perform the build in VS2010. VS2012 will still load your solution, but it will ignore (unload) your setup project. The same .sln will open up fine in VS2010 and VS2012.